# Table isn't visible in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop

I have created a table in Mysql, "A"

And I have created a database in Hive - "hiveankit"

When I try to import table A to the target database with the following command:

```
[training@localhost ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/march2015 --username root --table A -m 1 --target-dir  hiveankit;
```

This is the result:

```
16/07/02 08:53:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 15 records.

[training@localhost ~]$ hive;
Hive history file=/tmp/training/hive_job_log_training_201607020853_1580004608.txt
hive> show databases;
OK
default

hiveankit

Time taken: 3.029 seconds

hive> use hiveankit;
OK
Time taken: 0.044 seconds

hive> select * from A;
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:14 Table not found A
```

Why I am getting this error.

Am I missing any steps?

Comment: try to give full name of table  dbname.table...   and try to check if table exists . show tables ;

Comment: `Table not found A`... have you checked your table exists or was created?

Answer (score 0):

The import command should have **"--hive-table"**, **"--create-hive-table"** and **"--hive-import"** options to automatically create Hive table during sqoop import. I have modified your code by adding these options (see below). Without these options, the Sqoop import will only copy the data to HDFS and a Hive table will NOT be created.

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/march2015 --username root --table A --hive-table ${hive_db_name}.A --create-hive-table --hive-import -m 1 --target-dir  hiveankit;
```